# how to save previous page clikable url in database using php?

Tags: php, ajax, database, url, save

i have following div in project. after clicking on "request for demo" button , it will redirect to next window to registration form (link is mentioned in javascript function). i want to save relevant div id in database after clicking on button and save register.

following is my html and javascript

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pos-vertical">
                <span><b>Supermarkets, Fruits & Vegetables</b></span>
                <hr>                    
                <p>Uninterrupted fast billing, inventory control, CRM & Loyalty programs makes your shoppers happier</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="dwmld-btn">Free Download</button>
                <!--<button type="button" onclick="openWin()" class="btn btn-default" id="demo-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demoModal">Request for Demo</button>-->
                <button type="button" onclick="openWin()" class="modalBtn btn btn-default" id="Supermarkets, Fruits and Vegetables" >Request for Demo</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pos-vertical">
                <span><b>Grocery & Departmental Stores</b></span>
                <hr>
                <p>POS for grocery, departmental store, hypermarket and convenience store with GSmartPOS</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="dwmld-btn">Free Download</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="openWin()" class="modalBtn btn btn-default" id="Grocery and Departmental Stores" >Request for Demo</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pos-vertical">
                <span><b>Pharmacy, Medical Shop POS</b></span>
                <hr>
                <p>Prefilled drug index, update stock position and bill from Day One. Manage batches and expiry with ease</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="dwmld-btn">Free Download</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="openWin()" class="modalBtn btn btn-default" id="Pharmacy Medical Shop POS" >Request for Demo</button>
            </div>
        <br>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pos-vertical">
                <span><b>Apparel & Footwear</b></span>
                <hr>
                <p>POS Features like matrix-inventory, non-moving stock analysis, can help keep inventory latest and fashionable</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="dwmld-btn">Free Download</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="openWin()" class="modalBtn btn btn-default" id="Apparel and Footwear" >Request for Demo</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pos-vertical">
                <span><b>Electrical & Electronics POS</b></span>
                <hr>
                <p>Perfect solution to manage serialized inventory for mobile, computer electrical and electronics shops</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="dwmld-btn">Free Download</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="openWin()" class="modalBtn btn btn-default" id="Electrical and Electronics POS" >Request for Demo</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 pos-vertical">
                <span><b>Fashion Jewellery Shop</b></span>
                <hr>
                <p>An integrated, modular & scalable POS for furniture, glass & crockeries, opticals, music, toys & baby shop retail</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="dwmld-btn">Free Download</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="openWin()" class="modalBtn btn btn-default" id="Fashion Jewellery Shop" >Request for Demo</button>

            </div>
        </div>
```

following function is called on each div button,

```
<script>
function openWin() {
window.open("register.php");
}
</script>
```

after clicking on each div button following form will be open in new window,

```
<div class="register">

        <div class="container">
        <div class="row main">
            <div class="main-register main-center">
                <form class="" method="post" id="contact-form">                     
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="register-icon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="name"  placeholder="Enter your Name"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                            
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="register-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Enter your Email"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">                            
                        <div class="cols-sm-10">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="register-icon"><i class="fa fa-phone fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_no"  placeholder="Enter your contact number"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<input type="hidden" id="requestType">
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block register-button submit">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <span class="success" style="display:none">Thank You for Register with us.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

form will be save using ajax and php

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".modalBtn").click(function(){
var formName = $(this).attr("id");
$('#requestType').val(formName);
$('.success').hide();
$('.error').hide();
$('#contact-form').show();
$("#demoModal").modal();
});
$(".submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#name").val();
var requestType = $('#requestType').val();
var contact_no = $("#contact_no").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
//alert(requestType);
var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&contact_no=' + contact_no + '&email=' + email+ '&requestType=' + requestType;

    if(name=='' || contact_no=='' || email=='')
     {
    $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
    $('.error').show();
    }
    else
    {
   $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
 url: "register.php",
 data: dataString,
 success: function(){
 $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
 $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
 $('#contact-form').hide();

 }
  });
 }
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Php code to insert data is,

```
<?php 
require('connection.php');

if($_POST) {

$id = $_POST['regid'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$contact_no = $_POST['contact_no'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$requestType = $_POST['requestType'];


    if ($id == '') {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO registration(name,contact_no,email,requestType) VALUES ".
            "('".$name."', '".$contact_no."', '".$email."','".$requestType."')";
    } 
    $query_result = mysql_query( $sql );
    if(!$query_result ) {
        echo 'Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error();
    } else {
        //header("Location: lead-view.php?s=Y");
        $successMsg = 'Record instered successfully';
    }
    }
    ?>
```

i want save those div id as in url after submitting form of relevant dive click button. url will be save in "requestType" field in database. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of sessionStorage for passing the requestType value.
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/

While calling openWin() pass the div value to it. For example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="openWin('abc')" class="modalBtn btn btn-default" id="Supermarkets, Fruits and Vegetables" >Request for Demo</button>
```

Then save this value in sessionStorage as follows:

```
function openWin(div_value) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("registerType", div_value); 
  window.open("register.php");
}
```

You can retrieve this variable in register.php:

```
var registerType = sessionStorage.getItem("registerType");
```

Add this value to the hidden input control in register form and save it to database.

```
<input type="hidden" id="requestType">
```

Comment: but form will be save register.php

Comment: after clicking on each div button same register.php form will be open in new window and and save in datbase